# How to get Todo items with today as deadline

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

so I'm still creating my to-do list app, and I want to render all the items that have today's date as the deadline so as to remind the user of the pending tasks.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class ToDo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    todo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    end = models.DateField()
    start = models.DateField()
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner} - {self.todo}'
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    activities = ToDo.objects.all()
    today = ToDo.objects.get(end=datetime.date.today)
    todo = ToDo.objects.count()
    complete = ToDo.objects.filter(completed=True).count()
    percent = complete * 100 // todo 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            search = request.POST.get('todo')
            activities = ToDo.objects.filter(todo__icontains=search)
            
        except:
            search = request.POST.get('end')
            activities = ToDo.objects.filter(end=search)

    context = {
        'activities' : activities,
        'percent' : percent,
        'today' : today,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

I imported DateTime in my views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!

```
today = ToDo.objects.get(end=datetime.date.today)
```

Is the problem. get() is used to fetch a single row, you want all the matching rows which is done by `filter`. you are also sending in the function `today`, instead of calling it with `today()`.

Do this:

```
today = ToDo.objects.filter(end=date.today())
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
from django.utils import timezone

def index(request):
    today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

    deadline_today = ToDo.objects.filter(
        end__year=today.year,
        end__month=today.month,
        end__day=today.day
    )

    context = {
        ...
        'today' : deadline_today ,
    }
```